# How to shutdown a windows tablet from a UWP application running in assigned access mode?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, kiosk-mode, windows-10-universal

I have a UWP app running in assigned access mode on a windows tablet without a physical keyboard. Once the user finishes the operation I want to let the user shutdown the tablet ( Can't Alt+CTRL+DEL and shutdown as there is no physical keyboard). I know there are no API from UWP to shutdown the tablet. but is there any workarounds? How is Microsoft handling this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

This is not achievable within UWP application, which runs inside an App Container, and don't have such privilege.

However, you can try out the Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps. Essentially, it allows you UWP app to call Win32 API hosted in a different process, which runs outside of the App container.

Inside your brokered component, you can use below code to shut down your PC.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(psi);
```

Below is the brokered WinRT component template for VS2015
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d2e9cac0-66a8-464a-a902-55ae765c8e6e?tduid=(c5f2776eb12ea55b8926d0c075062c9d)(256380)(2459594)(TnL5HPStwNw-gN1OuW5VyKxMyOTAH.bK0w)()

Below is a very good example for creating brokered components for UWP,
https://xamltips.wordpress.com/2015/11/13/brokered-component-for-uwp-on-windows-10/

For more information, see to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx

Comment: I used a windows service interacting with App using TCP. and it worked!

Comment: Ha, that's also a hack.

Comment: @Suneesh I tried the same thing, but UWP doesn't allow loop back. did you use "checknetisolation loopbackexempt" to exempt the application?

Comment: @Sam I ran a windows service with TCP server which ran on elevated privilege. I can't tell you for sure, but I think I have added code in the service installer to add "checknetisolation loopbackexempt" for the app. I don't have the source code of the app now.

Comment: @Jackie, using shutdown.exe shows me a login screen briefly. Could it be avoided? I tested that login screen does not come when not in assigned access mode (i.e. running an app from the desktop).