# Restart a windows tablet from a UWP application?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml, windowsiot

I have UWP application running at kiosk mode in Tablet with Window 10. I would like to restart Tablet from my app. My installed UWP SDK version is - 10.0.18362.0. So I added into manifest:

```
<Package
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
 xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
 xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
 xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10"
 IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">

  <Capabilities>
     <Capability Name="internetClient" />
     <!-- Add the capability here -->
     <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
     <DeviceCapability Name="wifiControl" />
     <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth" />
```

And try to restart system in button event handler:

```
    private async void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        });
    }
```

And I get the error:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException - (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

There is my extensions:

[image]

I couldn't find Windows IoT Extension there. Maybe this is the reason? How can I restart my tablet programmably.

**UPD: I installed SDK with IoT Extension and added reference it does't help.**

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid your tablet doesn’t support this operation you want to achieve. This API only supports Windows IOT devices. It applies to the device with Windows IOT system.

Comment: Maybe I should use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`?

Comment: you can include a companion Win32 app with your package and launch it with FullTrustProcessLauncher. You'll probably need elevation too, if you're going to reboot the system. [Here's a walkthrough](https://sureshkumarct.wordpress.com/2019/09/22/app-elevation-breaking-out-of-the-uwp-sandbox/)

Comment: UWP applications are sandboxed, you can’t launch other processes directly through Process.Start(). 
You could try to use [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/dn630195(v=win.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to achieve it. then UWP app can call Win32 API hosted in a different process.

Comment: Please refer to the [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604593/how-to-shutdown-a-windows-tablet-from-a-uwp-application-running-in-assigned-acce), then replace **new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/s /t 0")** with  **new ProcessStartInfo("shutdown", "/r /t 0")** to achieve restart .